# A simple console-based banking system

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented

I am an amateur. I have been  coding for 3 months now.

If you have any comments,suggestion or critics about my code please feel free to speak up(i am urging you to).
I want to be a really good engineer.

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef BANKSYS_H
#define BANKSYS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class bank_application {

public:
    void register_acc();
    void deposit();
 
    void withdraw();
    void sign_in();
    void menu();


private:
    string account_holder{};
    double account_balance{};
    long int account_num{};
    
};


void bank_application::menu() {
    int option_pick{};
    cout << "OPTIONS \n 1> Withdraw \n 2> deposit " << endl;
    cin >> option_pick;

    switch (option_pick) {

    case 1: {
        withdraw();

        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {

        deposit();
        break;
    }


    }


}
void bank_application::register_acc() {
    cout << "Type in your full name " << endl;
     getline(cin >> std::ws, account_holder);
     cout << "Type in your account number " << endl;
     cin >> account_num;
     cout << "registration succesful " << endl;
}

void bank_application::sign_in() {
    string full_name{};
    long int acc{};
    cout << "SIGN IN FORM : " << endl;
    cout << "please sign into your account : type in your full name  " << endl;
    getline(cin >> std::ws, full_name);

    cout << "please type in your account number " << endl;
    cin >> acc;

    if ((full_name == account_holder) && (acc == account_num)) {
        cout << "log in succesful ..........." << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "log in failed " << endl;
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }


}

void bank_application::deposit() {

    long int deposit_amount{};
    cout << "how much do you want to deposit " << endl;
    cin >> deposit_amount;
    account_balance += deposit_amount;

    
        cout << "you have succesfully deposited " << deposit_amount << "$" << "\n " << "account balance is " << account_balance << endl;
        
}
void bank_application::withdraw() {
    long int withdrawal_amount{};
    cout << "type in the amount you want to withdraw " << endl;
    cin >> withdrawal_amount;

    if (account_balance < withdrawal_amount)
        cout << "operation cancelled " << endl;
    else
        account_balance -= withdrawal_amount;
  
    cout << "you have succesfully withdrawn " << withdrawal_amount << "\n " << "account balance is " << account_balance << endl;




}





#endif
```

This is my main cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "banksys.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    bank_application b_application;
    cout << "welcome to starcity bank , please register  " << endl;
    b_application.register_acc();
    cout << "now please sign in " << endl;
    b_application.sign_in();
    char reply{};
    while (true) {
        b_application.menu();
        cout << "Are you done [Y/N] " << endl;
        cin >> reply;
        if ((reply == 'Y') || (reply == 'y'))
            continue;
        else
            break;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## General Observations

Not bad for a beginner, but definitely needs improvement. The functions are generally properly sized and simple (good thing). The include guards are good, I prefer this style over `#pragma once`.

The object oriented design needs some work. There should be multiple classes, one of the classes should be `account`.

The indentation in the switch statement in `bank_application::menu()` is questionable.

The vertical spacing needs work, there are too many blank lines, and blank lines are missing where they should be such as between these 2 functions.

```
void bank_application::menu() {
    int option_pick{};
    cout << "OPTIONS \n 1> Withdraw \n 2> deposit " << endl;
    cin >> option_pick;

    switch (option_pick) {

    case 1: {
        withdraw();

        break;
    }
    case 2:
    {

        deposit();
        break;
    }


    }


}
void bank_application::register_acc() {
    cout << "Type in your full name " << endl;
     getline(cin >> std::ws, account_holder);
     cout << "Type in your account number " << endl;
     cin >> account_num;
     cout << "registration succesful " << endl;
}
```

## Avoid `using namespace std;`

If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

You should definitely avoid putting `using namespace std;` in a header file.

## Prefer C++ Container Classes

The 3 array declared in the class `bank_application` are using the old C programming style arrays. The C++ Standard Library (STL) provides many container classes that would be preferable, such as [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). In this particular case `std::vector` would probably be better.

## File Organization

Unlike Java and C#, C++ has header files and source files. There are libraries such as the `boost` libraries that do put all the code in the header files, but generally in C++ data definitions such as classes, structs and enums are defined in header file, and the executable code is in C++ source files. The code is organized this way to improve build times and to reduce link time errors. The function definitions (not the declarations) should be in a file probably called `banksys.cpp`. The file `banksys.h` should only contain the class declaration.

This organization also allows bugs in the code to be corrected without forcing recompilation of the source files that include the header file.

## Prefer `'\n'` over `std::endl`

For performance reasons output lines are generally terminated with '\n', std::endl performs a file flush after output, which requires a system call. System calls are generally expensive time wise.

Comment: Wow, such similar timing and contents :) Note that there aren't any arrays in OP's `bank_application`, those are braces instead of brackets. It only supports one account.

Answer (score 2):

## Reconsider the structure of your program

It's great that you have working code. However, if you'd want to extend this program in the future, you might want to reconsider how to structure it. At the moment, there are two things that I immediately recognize as problematic:

- A `class bank_application`. This sounds like a class that does too many things. You should try to make classes that are just responsible for a single thing. A whole bank application has to deal with many things, like managing a list of bank accounts, handling transactions to/from those accounts, and interaction with the user. I would instead create a `class bank` and a `class account`, and think of how to separate the user interface from the [business logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_logic).
- Part of the user interaction is done inside `bank_application`, part of it is done in `main()`. It would be much better if all UI is done in one place.

## Avoid `using namespace std`

Don't use `using namespace std` in header files, it can cause issues with other code that does not expect this, see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for reasons why.

While you can safely use it inside a source file, I would recommend avoiding it entirely: it doesn't add that many characters to your code, and in return it's now clear what things come from the standard library and what comes from elsewhere. You can also do a more limited form of `using`, for example:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
```

Will just pull in `cout` and `cin` into the global namespace, and will leave the rest untouched. This leads to fewer surprises.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

[Instead of `std::endl`, just write `'\n'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n). They are both nearly equivalent, but `std::endl` also explicitly forces a flush of the output, which is often unnecessary and might hurt performance. If you need to flush the output, you can always do so explicitly by writing:

```
std::cout.flush();
```

## Don't use floating point numbers for money

[Never use floating point numbers for currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency). Floating point mathematics is not exact, and rounding errors will accumulate over time. Instead, store the balance as an integer that represents the smallest unit of currency. For example, the euro's smallest unit is the cent, so store the amount of cents.

If you do need to convert to/from `double`, only do so right before printing the amount or when reading an amount from the input.

## Missing error checking

When you are dealing with input and output, things can go wrong. You therefore should check whether I/O was done succesfully. Consider reading `reply` in `main()`. If this fails, for example because the terminal was closed or you hit `control-D` on Linux, `cin >> reply` will fail. You can detect this by checking if `std::cin.good()` is `true`. If you don't check it, the program will continue, but `reply` will not have been updated. If it contained a `Y` from a previous, succesful attempt to read, then your program will go into an infinite loop. You don't have to check every attempt to read or write, but do so in places where it matters, for example in `sign_in()`, do so after reading the account number.

If you do encounter an error, handle it in a sensible way: report the error to `std::cerr` (not `std::cout`), and if you cannot recover from the error, make sure your program quits with an appropriate error code, like `EXIT_FAILURE`. Note that just writing `EXIT_FAILURE` like in `sign_in()` doesn't do anything; write `std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.

## Use complete sentences, capitals and punctuation

Your programs will look much more professional if you write complete sentences, starting with a capital and ending with the appropriate punctuation. For example, instead of:

```
cout << "operation cancelled " << endl;
```

Write:

```
std::cout << "The operation has been cancelled.\n";
```

Some other small things:

- Don't add spaces at the end of a line.
- [Don't add a space before (semi)colons](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/67394/spaces-around-a-colon).
- Don't add unnecessary things, like all the dots after `"log in succesful"`.
- Be consistent; I see some lines that don't start with a capital, some do, and some are in all-caps. Even if you don't agree with some of the things I said, at least pick one style and stick with it.

Comment: Great minds think alike.